# Azure Devops Upload Image

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I am importing a lot of data into Azure Devops using python. I have all the pieces working. I can upload images, my issue is when I download the image from the Devops website it is not a valid file. I will share my image upload code.

```
def convertAttachmentToJsonBinary(attachmentPath):
    file = open(attachmentPath, 'rb')
    file_data = file.read()
    encoded_data = base64.b64encode(file_data)
    decoded_data = encoded_data.decode()
    data = "[" + decoded_data + "]"
    return data


def patchWorkItemWithAttachment(case_id, att_id, att_url):
    json_template = open("attachment.json", "r")
    json_data = json.load(json_template)
    json_data[0]['value']['url'] = att_url
    json_data[0]['value']['attributes']['comment'] = "Adding attachment"

    response = requests.patch(patch_workitem_url.replace("{id}", case_id), json=json_data, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

While I am uploading a new case, I create the case, add attachments, then patch the newly created case with the new attachment. Again all of this work. I can see the attachment in my case online, however when I download it the file is invalid.
[image: Image on Devops]
[image]

I have attempted to read the data as a byte array as follows:

```
def convertAttachmentToJsonBinary(attachmentPath):
    file = open(attachmentPath, 'rb')
    encoded_data = bytearray(file.read())

    data = "[" + str(encoded_data) + "]"
    return data
```

I get the same error, uploading the image works however downloading the image it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested again and found I can't open the url returned from uploading to attachment Rest API successfully. So the image has broken when uploading.

Please try to convert image to **byte array** with `bytearray(image_file.read())`.

Please replace the value of `<>`

```
import requests
import base64
from io import BytesIO

pat = 'xxx'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<org_name>/<image_name>/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=<filename.bmp>&api-version=6.0'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

#upload to attachment
with open("<image_path>", "rb") as image_file:
    # base64 doesn't work well
    # encoded_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    # decoded_data = encoded_data.decode()
    # data = "[" + decoded_data + "]"
    data = bytearray(image_file.read())

    r = requests.post(url, data=data, 
        headers=headers)

    print(r.text)

#connect wit with attachment
......
```

Comment: Hey, are you uploading with a python script or uploading through the web browser? When I upload any image type through the web interface I can download the image and it works. So something is up with the script.

Comment: Hello @Michael, I have tried to check the issue again, and upload the image successfully. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Very interesting I will give this a shot!

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with the new code.

Comment: Hello @Michael, can you open the url returned from attachment Rest API? Does it display the image well?